# Entity Framework 5 CodeFirst - "Column names in each table must be unique."

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm creating the following table on PostgreSQL:

```
create table dbo.user_ratings (
user_id int not null,
user_rated_id int not null,
value decimal not null,
status_id int not null,
created_at timestamp with time zone not null,
updated_at timestamp with time zone null,
user_comment text null,

primary key (user_id, user_rated_id),
foreign key (user_id) references dbo.users(id),
foreign key (status_id) references dbo.status(id),
foreign key (user_rated_id) references dbo.users(id));
```

When mapping the table using CodeFirst, I'm doing the following:

```
[Table("user_ratings", Schema="dbo")]
public class UserRating {

    [Key, Column("user_id", Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column("user_rated_id", Order = 1)]
    public int UserRatedId { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserRated { get; set; }

    [Column("status_id")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    [Column("user_comment")]
    public string UserComment { get; set; }

    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Column("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Well, so far, so good. When I try to query something, I'm getting the error below:

```
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'User_Id' in table 'user_ratings' is specified more than once.
```

What is wrong with this? When I remove the mapping related to the column `user_id`, it's passing, but it's not right. Can someone help me?

Thank you all!!!

Comment: With the Sql server provieder it should be `[Key, Column("user_id", Order = 0), ForeignKey("User")]`. Can the PostgreSQL provider deal with that?

Comment: And the same for `Status`.

Comment: Checking the exception deeper, I found that it's a sqlserver error. Why does sql server errors are being raised even I'm using PostgreSQL as a database?

Comment: did you try changing [Key, Column("user_id", Order = 0)] to [Key,Order = 0)]

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work. I solve the problem. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this error is related only to SQLServer databases. I still had some SQLServer configurations on my Web.config/App.config, that's why this error was appearing. Without SQLServer configurations, the error is gone.